# 500 Internal Server Error (Postman w/ Eve Integration)

Tags: python, mongodb, rest, postman, eve

Hi so I am currently with MongoDB & Eve to build a local RestAPI connection and it is giving me a 500 internal server error. I am following this tutorial

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/building-rest-apis-using-eve--cms-22961

and am currently at the "Validate User API". I followed the exact steps in the tutorial, however it is giving me a "500 Internal Server Error" when I try to GET the user's info.

https://cms-assets.tutsplus.com/uploads/users/442/posts/22961/image/val87878.png

This is where I get the error. So instead of the users info coming up I get an 500 internal server error. Why is this happening? Below is the code I have.

Settings.py

```
from Authenticate import Authenticate

RESOURCE_METHODS = ['GET', 'POST']

DOMAIN = {
    'user': {
        'additional_lookup': {
                'url': 'regex("[\w]+")',
                'field': 'username',
            },
        'schema': {
            'firstname': {
                'type': 'string'
            },
            'lastname': {
                'type': 'string'
            },
            'username': {
                'type': 'string',
                 'unique': True
            },
            'password': {
                'type': 'string'
            },
            'phone': {
                'type': 'string'
            },
        }
    }


}
```

api.py

```
from eve import Eve
from Authenticate import Authenticate

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Eve(auth=Authenticate)
    app.run()
```

Authenticate.py

```
from eve.auth import BasicAuth

class Authenticate(BasicAuth):
    def check_auth(self, username, password, allowed_roles, resource,
                   method):
        if resource == 'user' and method == 'GET':
            user = app.data.driver.db['user']
            user = user.find_one({'username': username,'password':password})
            if user:
                return True
            else:
                return False
        elif resource == 'user' and method == 'POST':
            return username == 'admin' and password == 'admin'
        else:
            return True
```

Comment: 500 error means you have an error in your python ... try looking at your log files for what the error is ...

Comment: Set your debug mode on (`DEBUG = True` in settings.py)  in order to get a stacktrace. If you can't sort it out, post the actual error so we can try to help.